# Phonegap multiplatform bluetooth app problems?

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I am planning on creating an app for ios and android (phonegap) that will connect via bluetooth to some hardware and was wondering if there would be any problems with the bluetooth for multiplatform code? I was warned by a Lecturer that Cordova had problems with this but Phonegap seems to have bluetooth plug-ins for ios and android. 
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be using Bluetooth LE? If so you can use this plugin, which I authored: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/